# how to "stop" and "start" kubernetes API deployments /pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a requirement to stop deployment by label name and start it again, via the API
also I need to do that for a group of deployments so I added label for each of them

so i know how to filter the deploymnet by desire label. but I found that if I would like to stop deployment from running, I do need to scale it down and changed the replica number to 0

is there any other option to do that via API? because now I should need to keep the replica for start (scale-up again) but this is a parameter that not easy to keep in a lifecycle of a service

so now the best option that I found is smth like :

```
PAYLOAD='[{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/replicas","value":"3"}]'
curl -X PATCH -d$PAYLOAD -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' $API_URL
```

but I am asking if there is smth else and if there is a group "stop /start" like in docker swarm that you can just run docker stack rm for example

Comment: if you just want the pods to be restarted, you can try `kubectl rollout restart`, see [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#updating-resources)

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia no , i need to use deployment and I need to do that. via the API

Comment: You can do that with API as `kubectl` does. To trigger a restart for all pods `kubectl` adds an annotation to all pods such as `restartedAt: <insert timestamp>`

Comment: @anemyte yes but I need to stop and not restart

Comment: This cannot be done the way you described. I don't get why you are doing this. Maybe there is better way of solving the problem you have, but you need to start with describing the problem, not the potential solution you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to run `kubectl scale deployments mydeployment --replicas=0` via API call, you can run below command

```
$ curl -k \
    -X PUT \
    -d @- \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    https://$ENDPOINT/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/deployments/$NAME/scale <<'EOF'

{
  "kind": "Scale",
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1beta1",
  ...
}
EOF
```

More examples can be found in [Openshift RestAPI documentations](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/rest_api/apis-apps/v1beta1.Deployment.html#Put-apis-apps-v1beta1-namespaces-namespace-deployments-name-scale).

Comment: thanks ! 
wneh I would like to start,  is there a way to get the number of the replicas that I need to set? or it smth that i will need to keep in memory or as a parameter

Comment: If you don't want to rollout, you should store it in a file etc, and then get old scale from there.

Answer (score 0):

How about a solution where you store number of replicas in annoatation:

```
export DEPLOYMENT_NAME=xxx

kubectl annotate deployments $DEPLOYMENT_NAME replicas-before=$(kubectl get deployments.apps $DEPLOYMENT_NAME  -ojsonpath="{.spec.replicas}")

kubectl scale deployment --replicas 0 $DEPLOYMENT_NAME

kubectl scale deployment --replicas $(kubectl get deployments.apps nginx -ojsonpath="{.metadata.annotations.replicas-before}") $DEPLOYMENT_NAME
```

This does not require additional saving the state externally. You save the current state in an annotation in this example called `replicas-before`, and then scale down the deployment to 0. If you want to restore the number or replicas, just read the replicas from annotation and scale the deployment up to this value.

I know you asked for a solution using k8s api. Just run the kubectl command with `-v=10` and see what api requests are being sent.